# Cannot find registration form in Joomla

Tags: joomla3.4

I have  created new Login module and linked to the login menu in Joomla 3.4.1. Also created registration menu as described in docs and tutorials. The login form is showing - I have assigned the position to show in the template from module manager but I cannot view registration form - since there is no registration module. The registration page is showing empty with header and footer but with no body. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Is the module position valid for your template?
You van check this by enabling the "preview Module Position" under the template options.  To view the module position go to your home page e.g. hhtp://www.myhomepage.com/index.php?tp=1.  Please note the tp=1 ..
Now you can check if the module positions exists on your site.

Just let me know.

kind regards.

Comment: I followed your answer and I can find the position, which is position-4 for the template. I can view position-4 in both login and Registration page. But no sign of registration form at that position.